# Recommendations for resources for Embedded Testing

Tags: testing, embedded

We have recently decided that we need to get all embedded code development under more rigorous testing than an o-scope at the workbench, but I can't seem to find any good books, resources or other sources of information to accelerate the learning.  Does anyone have any recommendations of good sources of information specific to the embedded space?  Thanks

Comment: are you testing software or hardware or a combination?

Comment: Ultimately both firmware 8-bit micro and 32 bit micro, although we can start with start with firmware because we do functional test on the HW on the bench, we long term will need to find an automation path.

Answer (score 1):

Read everything ever written by Jack Ganssle.

Answer (score 0):

This book is a good start:

http://www.pragprog.com/titles/jgade/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c

There is an Agile Embedded Yahoo group which has had a fair bit of traffic lately about testing:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/AgileEmbedded/

And some other random sites:

http://www.renaissancesoftware.net/

http://www.atomicobject.com/pages/Embedded+Practices

http://www.agilerules.com/publications.phtml